# Is it possible to reference multiple foreign keys with one primary key?

Tags: database-design

Really hope this is the right place to ask this, but I just want to make sure this is modelled correctly.

I'm trying to create a relationship between store ownership (i.e., stores that bought other stores, or stores that are owned by other stores).

I have 3 tables:
Stores
parentStores
childStores

Essentially a store can have multiple children stores, but only one parent store. I just don't know the best way and type of relationship to link them--currently I have:

stores has a 1-to-Many relationship with parentStores (on storeID which is PK in stores and FK in parentStores)

stores has a 1-to-1 relationship with childStores (on storeID which is PK in stores and FK in childStores)

Is this the right way to go about it?

Sorry if it's an obvious question; new to 'backend' work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical 1-to-n relationship: one parent store is related to several child stores.

You don't need separate junction tables to model such a relationship, and it is best to avoid unnecessary tables.

You'd add a foreign key column `parent_store_id` to the `store` table that points to the parent store. If there is no parent store, the column contains `NULL`.

Comment: Ah so I'll only need two tables just to confirm? The default table is the stores one and IF a store is owned by another store, then it'll have a foreign key which links to the parent store table if I'm understanding you correctly! Thanks.

Comment: No, you need only a single table, `store`, that has a foreign key constraint that points to itself.

Comment: oh right, makes sense! Thanks a lot. I was confused because apparently can't set it up like that in PowerBI but managed to do it in SQL server. Thanks again!